# Optional Parameters with default values in VB6

Tags: c#, vb6

I am trying to recreate the following C# code in VB6:

```
private void ChangeTab(string tabName, bool clearAll = true)
{
    Yadyyada(tabName);

    if (clearAll)
    {
        DoMoreStuff();
    }
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub ChangeTab(ByVal tabName As String, Optional ByVal clearAll As Boolean)

    Yadyyada(tabName)

    If clearAll = True Then
        DoMoreStuff
    End If

End Sub
```

So far so good apart from the default parameter. Can I assign `clearAll` a default value of true in the method signature in the same way I can in C# or do I just need to do this at the start of the method?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried putting `= True` after the words 'As Boolean' but I get a compile error

Comment: @JMK: Are you sure the compile error isn't about something else? For example `Yadyyada(tabName)` statement is incorrect in VB6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow this takes me back.. can I ask why you're converting backwards technology-wise?

Anyway, you can use the Optional keyword:

```
Private Sub ChangeTab(ByVal tabName As String, Optional ByVal clearAll As Boolean = True)
```

Your issue is using ByVal. From memory, everything in VB6 was ByVal unless explicitly stated.

EDIT: I'm wrong. Default was ByRef.. it's been so long!

Comment: he has the `Optional`; it is the `= True` that was missing. But yeah, nostalgia trip!

Comment: `clearAll` should probably be explicitly `ByVal`; default is `ByRef` iirc

Comment: Yeah I updated my answer. I was so thrown off by this that I forgot to include what the actual issue was with the OP's version!

Comment: Thanks very much! Not really converting backwards, just trying to do something in one language that I know how to do in another language!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could do the same thing as in C#

```
Private Sub ChangeTab(ByVal tabName As String, Optional ByVal clearAll As Boolean = True) 
    Debug.Print "Value for clearAll=" & clearAll
End Sub
```

calling with

```
ChangeTab("AName")
```

will print True

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Private Sub ChangeTab(ByVal tabName As String, Optional clearAll As Boolean = True)

    Call Yadyyada(tabName)

    If clearAll Then
        DoMoreStuff
    End If

End Sub
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266305%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: +1 for linking to the docs. Why doesn't anyone read the docs?

Comment: @MarkJ: Maybe because it's not easy to find documentation for VB6 these days. AFAIR, after .NET took on, VB6 docs were removed from their old location. New location (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127540) is pretty hard to locate. I'm not sure if it's linked to from anywhere on main msdn site. I couldn't find it. All I found was migration instructions etc. I had to google a lot. And search results are mostly VB.NET now. With similar names it's hard to filter them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsMissing Function like this

```
Private Sub ChangeTab(ByVal tabName As String, Optional ByVal clearAll As Boolean)

    Yadyyada(tabName)

    If IsMissing(clearAll) = True Or clearAll = True Then
        DoMoreStuff
    End If

End Sub
```

My Mistake! Setting a default true value for optional parameter and check for this in code is the best solution!

```
Private Sub ChangeTab(ByVal tabName As String, Optional ByVal clearAll As Boolean = True)

    Yadyyada(tabName)

    If clearAll = True Then
        DoMoreStuff
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This won't work. IsMissing doesn't work for Boolean in VB6. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445048%28v=vs.60%29.aspx